# How do I continue the CUSTOM_AUTH flow for a CUSTOM_CHALLENGE after PASSWORD_VERIFIER runs?

Tags: amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-triggers

I have been following [this guide](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/extending-amazon-cognito-with-email-otp-for-2fa-using-amazon-ses/) to implement email OTP in AWS Cognito. I have my user pool and lambdas configured as the guide suggests, and am able to successfully trigger the `SRP_A` and `PASSWORD_VERIFIER` steps. However, I never continue to the `CUSTOM_CHALLENGE` flow - the `PASSWORD_VERIFIER` step always provides me with `AuthenticationResult` that contains the access token, which shows a successful login.

I tried taking away the `SRP_A` and `PASSWORD_VERIFIER` steps and just trying the `CUSTOM_CHALLENGE`, and that works and successfully sends me the OTP to my email. It seems whenever I use `PASSWORD_VERIFIER` I always get logged in and skip the rest of the `CUSTOM_AUTH` flow, even if many other `CUSTOM_AUTH` options are configured. My settings for the define auth lambda are the same as the guide's:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
        if (event.request.session && event.request.session.length === 1
            && event.request.session[0].challengeName === 'SRP_A'
            && event.request.session[0].challengeResult === true) {
            //SRP_A is the first challenge, this will be implemented by cognito. Set next challenge as PASSWORD_VERIFIER.
            event.response.issueTokens = false;
            event.response.failAuthentication = false;
            event.response.challengeName = 'PASSWORD_VERIFIER';
            
        } else if (event.request.session && event.request.session.length === 2
            && event.request.session[1].challengeName === 'PASSWORD_VERIFIER'
            && event.request.session[1].challengeResult === true) {
            //If password verification is successful then set next challenge as CUSTOM_CHALLENGE.
            event.response.issueTokens = false;
            event.response.failAuthentication = false;
            event.response.challengeName = 'CUSTOM_CHALLENGE';
            
        } else if (event.request.session && event.request.session.length >= 5
            && event.request.session.slice(-1)[0].challengeName === 'CUSTOM_CHALLENGE'
            && event.request.session.slice(-1)[0].challengeResult === false) {
            //The user has exhausted 3 attempts to enter correct otp.
            event.response.issueTokens = false;
            event.response.failAuthentication = true;
            
        } else if (event.request.session  && event.request.session.slice(-1)[0].challengeName === 'CUSTOM_CHALLENGE'
            && event.request.session.slice(-1)[0].challengeResult === true) {
            //User entered the correct OTP. Issue tokens.
            event.response.issueTokens = true;
            event.response.failAuthentication = false;
            
        } else {
            //user did not provide a correct answer yet.
            event.response.issueTokens = false;
            event.response.failAuthentication = false;
            event.response.challengeName = 'CUSTOM_CHALLENGE';
        }

        return event;
};
```

Even if I change the of the `issueTokens` key to false and `failAuthentication` to true, if I respond to the `PASSWORD_VERIFIER` step with the correct user/pass combo I will still log in successfully and it skips any other challenges.

Is there something configured incorrectly for my user pool? I've tried it with two separate user pools - one with MFA optional and one with MFA disabled, but the `CUSTOM_AUTH` flow still doesn't seem compatible with `PASSWORD_VERIFIER`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue here - as you're using the API, the call to `respondToAuthChallenge` must also be passed `Session` from the previous response. On a separate challenge I passed `Session` because I got an error that it was required when I didn't pass it, but for `PASSWORD_VERIFIER` you don't need `Session` set, likely because you can use it to create a session itself. Since I was continuing from the `SRP_A` flow I needed to provide the same session value from that flow.